# Sort input box move UP/Down works only for first set of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have merged my last two demos and now there is a conflict.

Here is my 2 demos

1. Adding multiple input boxes  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/6/)**
2. Sort Up/Down - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P2XDc/9/)**

**[Merged demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/5/)**

If you look at merged demo, the sort option is working only for first input box. Which mean you can move only first text box to up and down, other up/down button of respective text boxes are not working at all.

I need it to work as the sort Up/Down demo, all the button should work to move respective input boxes up or down.

Thanks in advance!!

Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(":radio").click(function(){
         $(".test").hide();
         var show = $(this).attr("data-show");
         $("#"+show).show(300)
     });

        $filtr = $('.filtr');

        $filtr.on('click', '.add', function(){
            $(this).closest('.loop').clone().appendTo( $(this).closest('.test') );
        });

        $filtr.on('click', '.del', function(){
           $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
        });

        $('#1lev, #2lev, #3lev').hide();

     //For sort up/down
     function moveUp(item) {
    var prev = item.prev();
    if (prev.length == 0)
        return;
    prev.css('z-index', 999).css('position','relative').animate({ top: item.height() }, 250);
    item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: '-' + prev.height() }, 300, function () {
        prev.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.insertBefore(prev);
    });
}
function moveDown(item) {
    var next = item.next();
    if (next.length == 0)
        return;
    next.css('z-index', 999).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: '-' + item.height() }, 250);
    item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: next.height() }, 300, function () {
        next.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.insertAfter(next);
    });
}

$(".filtr").sortable({ items: ".loop", distance: 10 });
$('button').click(function() { 
    var btn = $(this);
    var val = btn.val();
    if (val == 'up')
        moveUp(btn.parents('.loop'));
    else
        moveDown(btn.parents('.loop'));
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/7/

I did changes in only one line

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
```

Is this your requirement? Let me know your comments.

Comment: I think $("button").on("click", function() { should also work but it is not can you explain

Comment: Yes this is what I need. Could you pls explain?

Comment: Plz add this query to your question

Comment: basically it is because .click only attaches the events to already existed button when it is called but when you move the objects it re create the buttons which cause de-attach of the events on the other hand .on (.live) watches the DOM and also attach element even they added to DOM after call. I personally use event in the html like <button onclick="moveUP(this)"> so you can use this as you already did.

Comment: @Onur <button onclick="moveUP(this)"> is against separation of concern principle you are mixing javascript with HTML

Answer (score 0):

Instead of document selector choose the closest parent selector

```
$('.filtr').on('click','button' ,(function() {
```

In order to study the difference between the two you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418991/when-using-jquery-on-why-use-document-vs-the-element-itself) 
You may also read **Direct and delegated events**  section of [.on event](http://api.jquery.com/on/)