# Jquery fileupload library not calling onchange function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using Jquery fileupload library(blue emp, https://blueimp.net) for uploading the file.
I have table consisting fileupload control in each row.

```
<table id="recordTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                    
                            <th>Question Number</th>
                            <th>Question Text</th>
                            <th>Supported Document</th>
                            <th>File Upload Status</th>                                 
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>                       
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ques_id">17</td>
                                <td class="ques_text">asddsf</td>
                                <td class="ques_file"><input type="file" name="supportingDocument" accept="application/pdf" id="uploadSupportingDoc"></td>
                                <td class="fileuploadSuccess"></td>                                 
                                <td><a href="#" id="deleteButton" class="btn btn-primary">delete</a></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="ques_id">18</td>
                                <td class="ques_text">dfgdfg</td>
                                <td class="ques_file"><input type="file" name="supportingDocument" accept="application/pdf" id="uploadSupportingDoc"></td>
                                <td class="fileuploadSuccess"></td>                                 
                                <td><a href="#" id="deleteButton" class="btn btn-primary">delete</a></td>
                            </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Onchange event for the fileupload, what I am doing here is sending data of first column i.e questionId(it's unique id column)

```
$('#uploadSupportingDoc').on("change", function(){ 
   console.log("on change called!");
   var questionId = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text(); 

   console.log("fileUpload called with Id =>"+questionId);
   uploadFile(questionId); 
});
```

asdsad

```
function uploadFile(questionId) {


 $('#uploadSupportingDoc').fileupload({
    url: 'uploadSupportingDoc.html',
    formData: {questionId: questionId },
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpe?g)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 100,
    dropZone: null,
    pasteZone: null,
    fileInput: $(this),
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function(e, data){
             $(this).closest('tr').children('td.fileuploadSuccess').html('<img src="./img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Uploading..." />');
           data.submit();
    },
    done: function (e, data){
        var response = data.result.files[0];
        console.log("done");
        if(!response.isRequestValid)
        {
            window.location = "requestDenied.html";
        }
        else
        {

            if(response.status)
            {

                $(this).closest('tr').children('td.fileuploadSuccess').html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>")

            }
            else
            {
                $(this).parent().siblings().find(".fileuploadSuccess").html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>")

            }
        }
    },
    fail: function(e, data){
        console.log("failed");

        console.log(data.jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(data.jqXHR+"\m");
    },
    always: function (e, data){
        console.log("in always");
    }
 });
```

}

what is happening here is **only on first attemp**  $('#uploadSupportingDoc').on("change", function(){ }) is getting called,
 after that **every subsequent change event is directly calling** $('#uploadSupportingDoc').fileupload() function. why is it happening?

Comment: Try by changing the syntax as : `$('#uploadSupportingDoc').on("change", function()` instead `$(document).on('change','#uploadSupportingDoc',function(){ // your code goes here.. })`

Comment: okay! it's working. what is really happening in my code? please post explanation and answer in answer section so that I can give you deserved credits.

Comment: Glad to help you. For the difference in between these two syntax kindly look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418991/when-using-jquery-on-why-use-document-vs-the-element-itself).