# How to fire only one of the event if both of them occur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I used this code to handle to event , but I want to fire one time if both of them or one of them occur.

```
$(document).on("keypress blur", ".pollOptionInput", function(e) {
  if (e.type == 'focusout' || e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addPollOption();
    $('.btnAdd').focus();
  }
});
```

My code fire two time if I press enter key .
how can I solve my problem ?

Comment: `e.type` will never be `focusout`..Try with `keypress`

Comment: @Rayon but e.type is `focusout` in console

Comment: Try `$(document).on("keypress blur", ".pollOptionInput", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode || e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    addPollOption();
    $('.btnAdd').focus();
  }
});
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you expect?
You can pass the function on document this way:

```
    var myFunction = function() {
    addPollOption();
    $('.btnAdd').focus();
    //if you don't want an event occurs multiple times after one call:
    e.stopPropagation();
    }

    $('document')
    .keypress(myFunction)
    .blur(myFunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

It works without any problems. Maybe you attach event twice and that's the problem.
Note that i changed a way of event attaching - [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418991/when-using-jquery-on-why-use-document-vs-the-element-itself)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".pollOptionInput").on("keypress blur", function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'blur' || e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
      //addPollOption();
      //$('.btnAdd').focus();
      console.log('EVENT!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="pollOptionInput" />
<input type="text" class="pollOptionInput" />
<input type="text" class="pollOptionInput" />
```