# js click event on empty div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three divs as below:

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/352up7nd/).

```js
$(document).on('click', '.top', function (e) {     
  console.log("Empty space clicked"); 
});
```

```css
.top{    
    width: 208px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: #F44336;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ea1c0d;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1);
    padding: 3px 8px;
    cursor: auto;
  }
 .inner_1{
    font-size: 12px;
 }
  .inner_2{
   font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 
 .inner_1:hover,  .inner_2:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div class="inner_1">Top content: This is full width</div>
  <div class="inner_2">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the jsfiddle, when the `.top` is clicked, it shows a log.

However, I want to make it so that it shows the log ONLY when the empty space is clicked and not when `inner_1` or `inner_2` div class is clicked (as it shows the log when these two classes are clicked as of now).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use stopPropagation from jquery. This will stop all child divs from triggering parent onClick

```
$(document).on('click', '.top > div', function (e) {                    
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Edit:
Code above was building on what OP knows but this way is more efficient for the browser.

```
$('.top > div').on('click', function (e) {                    
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a quick question.  What is the purpose of `.top > div`?

Comment: @steveKim It selects all direct descendant (i.e. child) divs inside of `.top`. If the child content is not limited to divs only you could do `.top > *` to target any element. If you want to target all grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc. elements as well, use `.top *` as this selector targets any number of nested elements...

Comment: Oh i see. I understand now. Thank you very much.

Comment: One final note. This solution works well. However, for efficiency purposes, you want your binding selector (in this case `document`) to be as close to the `.top` selector as possible, preferably a direct parent. Otherwise, the events may end up traversing several levels up the DOM to reach this binding. You may not notice any change for smaller applications, but for larger ones, it will be rough in terms of memory management.

Comment: Hmm, somehow it is not working. I mean, when I click the contents (inside of two inner divs), I get the log and not when I click the empty space. I am trying to do the opposite of it (that I get a log when I click the empty space and not when I click the texts). Could you take a look at it? (https://jsfiddle.net/352up7nd/2/)

Comment: You replaced your old code. Guess i should have let you know that it was an addition to your other code. You are created Event Listeners. The one you had before was listening to the click of the ".top" element(s). Mine was   Adding onClick listener for the ".top > div" element(s) which prevented the browser from executing the ".top" click event. AKA include both XD

Comment: @War10ck I am curious about the efficiency you mentioned. I have several functions using `$(document).on('click')`. Now would it be more efficient to change all of them to `$('.class').on('click')`?

Comment: Yes. And personally much easier to read. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418991/when-using-jquery-on-why-use-document-vs-the-element-itself